# Pentaho Data Integration (kettle) 6.0.1 will not recognize command line argument

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am transferring a kettle Job to a new production server and when I call the initial kettle job, it will not recognize the command-line argument that I pass.

Here is the script/job call I am using:

`/path/pdi-6.0.1/data-integration/kitchen.sh -file /path/kettle_job.kjb /command_line_argument_path >logfile"`

The problem is that the command_line_argument_path is a path where files are supposed to be stored, but instead of going to that path, they are being put inside of the location: `/path/pdi-6.0.1/data-integration`

The same call is working on a testing server and the permissions for all the places this job touches is the same across both servers, so I am confused on why it is not putting the files inside the command line argument path as the testing server does.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: can you re-explain the problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. Basically when I initiate the kitchen.sh along with the kettle job I pass that value "command line argument path". The kettle job doesn't use this path when I make a step called "get system info" and request that it uses "command line argument 1".  I have it set up the same across two servers and it works on one but not on another. I've checked permissions and they all seem the same.